# Can't remember which wallet was used?

Tags: myetherwallet

Started a miner a few months ago and it's going to pay out a block in the next day. Problem is I can't remember where I created the wallet.

Address: CbBb080bD1D4Ed47E665d9d24Fb56791632b929b

Any way to trace where I can login to wallet?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that. If you have your private key or have a JSON backup file, you can login to your address at sites such as https://www.myetherwallet.com/. This way, you can send and receive funds to that address. Remember, as long as you have the address and private key, you have your account.